# "No previous prototype for function" warning

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

i use shareKit to myself program .

but in the FBConnectGlobal, there are some warning,

```
NSMutableArray* FBCreateNonRetainingArray() {
  CFArrayCallBacks callbacks = kCFTypeArrayCallBacks;
  callbacks.retain = RetainNoOp;
  callbacks.release = ReleaseNoOp;
  return (NSMutableArray*)CFArrayCreateMutable(nil, 0, &callbacks);
}
```

like this method, it warning:"No previous prototype for function FBCreateNonRetainingArray"

Comment: Have you added the prototype of the function in the .h file ?

Comment: yes, i did......NSMutableArray* FBCreateNonRetainingArray();

Comment: i have solved this problem, add static before .

Comment: Where do you add the static? Tried in both .h and .m file, both didn't work.

Comment: No,just .m  ,and delete prototype of the function in the .h file

Comment: Then I get a linker error: `Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_FBCreateNonRetainingArray", referenced from:
      -[FBSession initWithKey:secret:getSessionProxy:] in FBSession.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To clarify Eric Dchao's answer above, someone at facebook apparently didn't put a "static" in front of that BOOL?

Anyways, changing from this

```
BOOL FBIsDeviceIPad() {
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 30200
  if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    return YES;
  }
#endif
  return NO;
}
```

to this

```
static BOOL FBIsDeviceIPad() {
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 30200
  if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    return YES;
  }
#endif
  return NO;
}
```

fixed it for me.

Comment: I wonder how many people have had to figure this out? Sloppy coding, Facebook!

Comment: The answer by daveswen below is correct for exporting a function to be used throughout the project (as one would assume is the purpose for this type of function). The Derek Bredensteiner answer will not work for sharing the function, since (in the c language) the "static" keyword is used to prevent exporting the symbol for the linker.

Answer (score 62):

According to c standard, declaring the prototype as

```
NSMutableArray* FBCreateNonRetainingArray(void);
//      --------------->                  ^^^^   
// Yes, with the void as the parameter
```

solves the issue.

Comment: Assuming you're trying to export the function (i.e. its prototype is in the header) this is the ACTUAL thing you want to do.  If your function is statically scoped (i.e. should only visible from the file in which it is defined) then sure, putting static in front of it as others suggest will do the job too.  When working with huge/legacy code bases that don't have the void in the empty parens, sure, turning off the warning may be the easier approach.

Comment: But when you do want the function to be available outside the file (I use these for number and date formatters that I reuse throughout my projects) this is the most elegant answer.

Answer (score 28):

**UPDATE**: Disable warnings is not a good solution, check @Derek Bredensteiner's answer.

In Xcode 4, go to your project's Build Settings. Search for "prototype". There should be an option called "Missing Function Prototypes"; disable it.

via [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097660/how-to-handle-the-xcode-warning-no-previous-prototype-for-function/7097749#7097749)

Comment: Disabling warnings should be a last ditch response. In this case, there is an easy solution--declare the function prototype in the header if you mean to export it (or declare it static if it's use is to be limited to that one file).

Answer (score 7):

Is it a **global** function? Add "**static**" if it is only used in the current file.

The possible reason is as below:

no previous prototype for `foo'

This means that GCC found a global function definition without seeing a prototype for the function. If a function is used in more than one file, there should be a prototype for it in a header file somewhere. This keeps functions and their uses from getting out of sync

If the function is only used in this file, make it static to guarantee that it'll never be used outside this file and document that it's a local function