# How to handle the Xcode warning "no previous prototype for function..."?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, warnings

This warning is popping up a bunch in some third party libraries.

Is there a way to handle it without modifying the code (e.g. ignore the warning)?

If I have to modify the code to fix it how do I do it?

Here's one of the code blocks that's causing a warning:

```
BOOL FBIsDeviceIPad() {
 #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 30200
  if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
   return YES;
  }
 #endif
  return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Usually with warnings like this you can just define a function prototype at the top of your file, for instance:

```
BOOL FBIsDeviceIPad();
```

**But** in C a method with nothing between the braces, i.e. `()` actually implies there are an arbitrary number of parameters. Instead the definition should become `(void)` to denote **no** parameters:

```
BOOL FBIsDeviceIPad(void);

...

BOOL FBIsDeviceIPad(void) {
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 30200
  if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
   return YES;
  }
#endif
  return NO;
}
```

Comment: I am annoyed very much with this warning, and the "void" keyword in C methods definition explains all.

Comment: I too am annoyed: to make my project work without warnings, I had to change the code of something that wasn't mine: glew.c. I know I can build a library from it and link it with the project, but it's just easy to add glew.c. Thanks for the help!

Comment: for all who are still annoyed by this issue, update your Facebook SDK. New version is no longer having this issue.

Answer (score 29):

In Xcode4, go to your project's Build Settings. Search for "prototype". There should be an option called "Missing Function Prototypes"; disable it. You can also do this to the specific target(s) in question.

Comment: Although this is technically correct, I would suggest following @mattmook's advice as it points out the differences between () and (void).

Comment: This method however would refuse a lot of corrections to existing code that is "Technically" correct.

Answer (score 1):

There are no warnings if such a function is defined as inline.

This may suffice as long as your function is optimized for inline use.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w2887zk.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Another way of fixing the warning is to make the functions `static` so they're only visible within the file (specifically, can only be linked within the file's translation unit).

It seems like part of the use of this warning is that if you have a standalone function, you either want it usable in other implementation files, or only in the file where it's defined. This warning makes you be explicit about that choice, and helps you be aware if the header has diverged from the implementation.

If you want it usable in other implementation files, you should have its prototype in a header somewhere.

If you want it only usable in this file, then it should be static.