# Error: No previous prototype for function. Why am I getting this error?

Tags: c, prototype

// screen.h

```
#ifndef screen_h
#define screen_h

#define MAC  1
#define WIN  2
#define LNX  3

#ifdef PLATFORM 
# undef PLATFORM 
#endif

#define PLATFORM MAC

void screen_init();

#endif
```

// screen.c

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "screen.h"

#if PLATFORM == MAC

#include <curses.h> 

void screen_init(){
    erase();
}

#endif
```

I don't understand why it is not seeing my prototype in screen.h

Any suggestions/hints are appreciated!

Comment: What compiler are you using, and what is the exact message(s) that the compiler produces?

Comment: I haven't even tried compiling it yet. I want to fix this error before I do so.

Comment: Where is the error coming from if you're not compiling the program!?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076345/no-previous-prototype-for-function-warning <- according to this, the prototype should be void screen_init (void); (note the void as the parameter)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

> **ISO/IEC 9899:TC2 - 6.2.1.2:**
>   A function prototype is a declaration of a function that declares the types of its parameters.

An empty argument list in a function declaration indicates that the number and type of parameters is not known. You must explicitly indicate that the function takes no arguments by using the `void` keyword. Otherwise your function declaration does not count as a valid prototype.

```
void screen_init(void);
```

Comment: Isn't the message in the question what `-Wmissing-prototypes` gives? Your suggestions seems to be for `-Wstrict-prototypes` case.

Comment: note that only the function declaration requires adding `void` to the parameter list. The definition can just be left empty.

Answer (score 4):

I met this similar error minutes ago. After i'd added the relatived function declaration in head file, error's gone. 
Also, some said that canceling the compile option '-Wmissing-prototypes' should work, but i didn't have tried that. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

I just had this problem today.

I defined a function that just used internally

```
void func(void) {
}

int main(void) {
    func();
}
```

This will give me that warning.
I had to add the prototype at the beginning of the file to get rid of the warning.

```
void func(void);

void func(void) {
}

int main(void) {
    func();
}
```

Comment: Really?  What compiler emits that warning for a perfectly reasonable source (such as either of your source files above)?

Comment: It is an ARM C Compiler
This is the result:
16:31:58 **** Incremental Build of configuration Release for project peripheral_server ****
make all 
Building file: ../code/flash.c
Invoking: Cross ARM C Compiler
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -Os -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections 
../code/flash.c:72:6: warning: no previous prototype for 'lock_NVR' [-Wmissing-prototypes]
 void lock_NVR(unsigned int flags)
      ^~~~~~~~
Finished building: ../code/flash.c

Comment: No, `arm-none-eabi-gcc` is a GNU compiler.  And that error message can't come from the code you show (which has no line 72).

Comment: Is there anyway I can upload an attachment?

Comment: I'm seeing the same with `gcc 4.4.7` on x86. Instead of adding the prototype before the actual function definition I could add `static` to the function definition for functions which are only used within the same `.c` file to get rid of the warning.

Comment: Yes, that works too. Just tried it. Not sure why the compiler put this restriction in the source code level. I am a embedded firmware developer. My guess is the compiler want you to make sure that this function is positively being used. I know that compiler is able to remove the functions that not being used, but in firmware design there ARE some functions which are not referenced explicitly

Comment: See the gcc compiler option -Wmissing-prototypes.