# No previous prototype?

Tags: c, xcode, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error: No previous prototype for function. Why am I getting this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541768/error-no-previous-prototype-for-function-why-am-i-getting-this-error)

I have a function that I prototyped in the header file, however Xcode still gives me warning `No previous prototype for the function 'printBind'`. I have the function `setBind` prototyped in the same way but I do not get an warning for this function in my implementation.

**CelGL.h**

```
#ifndef Under_Siege_CelGL_h
#define Under_Siege_CelGL_h

void setBind(int input);
void printBind();

#endif
```

**CelGL.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "CelGL.h"

int bind;

void setBind(int bindin) { // No warning here?
    bind = bindin;
}

void printBind() { // Warning here
    printf("%i", bind);
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In C, this:

```
void printBind();
```

is not a prototype.  It declares a function that returns nothing (`void`) but takes an indeterminate list of arguments.  (However, that list of arguments is not variable; all functions taking a variable length argument list *must* have a full prototype in scope to avoid undefined behaviour.)

```
void printBind(void);
```

That's a prototype for the function that takes no arguments.

The rules in C++ are different - the first declares a function with no arguments and is equivalent to the second.

The reason for the difference is historical (read 'dates back to the mid-1980s').  When prototypes were introduced into C (some years after they were added to C++), there was an enormous legacy of code that declared functions with no argument list (because that wasn't an option before prototypes were added), so backwards compatibility considerations meant that `SomeType *SomeFunction();` had to continue meaning 'a function that returns a `SomeType *` but for which we know nothing about the argument list'.  C++ eventually added the `SomeType *SomeFunction(void);` notation for compatibility with C, but didn't need it since type-safe linkage was added early and all functions needed a prototype in scope before they were defined or used.

Note that C23 finally brings C into alignment with C++ and the empty parenthesis notation means that the function declaration is a prototype for a function taking no arguments.

Comment: Though I now understand the reason for the error, I do not really understand the usefulness of this feature. When would you define a function with an indeterminate parameter list and what exactly does this have to do with C++? Is this a useful feature in C++?

Comment: You can’t define a prototype with an indeterminate argument list in C++. In C++, that means “no arguments”, not “indeterminate arguments”.   The feature is not so much useful as a necessary concession to reality.  When C was standardized, the entire vast code base was written without prototypes; they hadn’t existed in C.  The empty parenthesis notation was all there was in pre-standard C. To have outlawed it would have killed the nascent C standard. That was still true for C99. It was less clear for C11, but was left unchanged.