# Apple Mach-O Link (Id) Error

Tags: c

My code is identical to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541768/error-no-previous-prototype-for-function-why-am-i-getting-this-error) question I asked earlier so there's no point in duplicating it here

This is the error I am getting:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_stdscr", referenced from:
      _screen_init in screen.o
  "_werase", referenced from:
      _screen_init in screen.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I've had this error in the past and I feel like it has something to do with a duplicate function name or something, but I have no idea how to debug this.

**EDIT:**

After adding the libncurses.dylib file to my project, the errors discussed above have disappeared, but a new error has emerged when I call screen_init(); in my main.cpp:

// main.cpp

```
#include "screen.h"

int main(){
   screen_init();
}
```

// new error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "screen_init()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Pretty much the same error except now in my main. Is there another library I am missing? These errors are very mysterious and not very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to add the library to your link phase, if you are going with XCode you should add it in project details:

- choose project details
- choose build phases tab
- open link binary with libraries part
- click the plus symbol
- add `libncurses.dylib` to your project.

Comment: I've gone ahead and added that library to my project and it took away the errors, but when I call screen_init(); from my main now, I am getting another Mach-O Link error. See my edit above for details.