# error: no previous prototype for 'check'

Tags: c, compiler-errors

In my program, I have a file called `hiker.c`. The appropriate contents of this file are below:

```
char** answer(char c)
{

// Initial scanf and check
    printf("Please input the character which you want to build your diamond with");
    if (check(c) == true) {
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        printf("Not a valid character");
        return NULL; 
    }


 ....
```

I have a `#include "check.h"` as a header in `hiker.c`. The contents of `check.h` are as below:

```
// Check Function for the input characters
bool check(char c)
{

int ascii = (int)c;
if (ascii < 122 && ascii > 97) {
    return false; 
            printf("Lowercase letters not allowed.");
} else if (ascii < 65 && ascii > 90) {
    return false; 
} else {
    return true; 
}

}
```

And now I get the error where it says:

```
check.h:5:6: error: no previous prototype for 'check' [-Werror=missing-prototypes] bool check(char c)
```

I do not understand the cause of this.

Comment: unrelated note : `ascii < 65 && ascii > 90` always false.

Comment: The problem is that you put a function in a header file. You're not supposed to do that.

Comment: @melpomene I get the same error if I change check.h to a check.c

Comment: Do NOT compare with 'true'  because 'true' can be anything except 0(false).  so this line: `if (check(c) == true) {`  should be: `if (check(c)) {` or `if (check(c) != false) {`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: No previous prototype for function. Why am I getting this error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541768/error-no-previous-prototype-for-function-why-am-i-getting-this-error)

Comment: the posted file contents of: check.h is not a valid header file.   A header file should contain function prototypes, inline functions, extern statements, macro definitions, enum definitions, union definitions, struct definitions.  It should not ever contain any other code (beyond inline functions)  It should also not ever contain variable declarations

Comment: Is there something confusing about: `check.h:5:6: error: no previous prototype for 'check'`  It says exactly what the compiler sees as the problem.  Suggest move the check() function to file `check.c`.  Then put the prototype for the check() function in `check.h`.  then `#include "check.h"` in both the check.c and hiker.c files.   I.E. 3 separate files.   BTW: be sure to place 'include guard' statements into the check.h file

Comment: Please indent the code consistently so it is easily readable by us humans

Comment: @user3629249 what do you mean 'include guard' statements. I also think that your last comment is the best answer for  this question

Comment: @user3629249 does C not have true defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a possible check.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "check.h"

// Check Function for the input characters
bool check(char c)
{
    int ascii = (int)c;

    if (ascii < 122 && ascii > 97)
    {
        return false; 
                printf("Lowercase letters not allowed.");
    }

    else if (ascii < 65 && ascii > 90)
    {
        return false; 
    }

    else
    {
        return true; 
    }

} // end function: check.c
```

here is the hiker.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "check.h"


char** answer(char c)
{

// Initial scanf and check
    printf("Please input the character which you want to build your diamond with");
    if (check(c) == true) {
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        printf("Not a valid character");
        return NULL; 
    }


 ....
```

and here is the check.h file

```
#ifndef CHECK_H
#define CHECK_H

#include <stdbool.h>

bool check(char c);

#endif // CHECK_H
```